# How to read data attribute value of first anchor on click event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to access data attributes using jQuery but not able read value.

### Here is my HTML:

```js
$(function() {

  $(document.body).on('click', '.remainingTimeDv .font-sm .cursorDefault', function(event) {
    var messageId = $(this).parents().closest('.leaveCommentDv').find('a:first').attr('data-ajax-coments-res');
    alert(messageId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messageContentRow">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="userName hover-no-underline">Erick Venere</a>
  <p></p>
  <p>Vel ab eius consequat Consequatur Labore sunt<br></p>
  <p></p>
  <div class="remainingTimeDv">
    <ul>
      <li class="font-sm">22 minutes ago
        <span class="cursorDefault" title="Emma Caldarera">(to Multiple Staff)</span>
      </li>
      <li class="brodcastText "></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="leaveCommentDv">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="leaveComment" data-ajax-coments-res="26" data-parent-message-id="0"><i class="chatGrey"></i>Leave a Comment</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="dig dig26" data-message-id="26" data-parent-message-id="0"><i class="thumbGrey"></i>Dig it</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="ajaxComentsRes26" class="ajaxComentsRes"></div>
</div>
```

On click of red border text, I want to get data attribute value from blue border text which is **data-ajax-coments-res** so can you please guide how to read data attribute value.

[image]

Comment: Use `.data('ajax-coments-res')`. But what is actually wrong with your code?

Comment: I am getting `undefined` as not able to get value.

Comment: While this may be unrelated to your problem I'll point out that `$(this).parents().closest('.leaveCommentDv')` is redundant, in that it selects all the ancestors of the `this` node, and then looks for the closest ancestor with the 'leaveCommentDv' class. This may work, but the call to `parents()` certainly seems unnecessary (unless the `this` node may also have the `leaveCommentDv` class name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `.closest()` and `.siblings()`.
(I am not fond of the `.parents()` method.)

Your code `.closest('.leaveCommentDv')` wasn't working because `.leaveCommentDv` is not an ancestor. I modified it to a correct ancestor `.remainingTimeDv`, and added `.siblings('.leaveCommentDv')` so that your `find()` can access the correct element.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.remainingTimeDv .font-sm .cursorDefault', function(event) {
  var messageId = $(this).closest('.remainingTimeDv').siblings('.leaveCommentDv').find('a:first').attr('data-ajax-coments-res');
  alert(messageId);
});
```

```css
.remainingTimeDv .font-sm .cursorDefault{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messageContentRow">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="userName hover-no-underline">Erick Venere</a>
  <p></p>
  <p>Vel ab eius consequat Consequatur Labore sunt<br></p>
  <p></p>
  <div class="remainingTimeDv">
    <ul>
      <li class="font-sm">22 minutes ago
        <span class="cursorDefault" title="Emma Caldarera">(to Multiple Staff)</span>
      </li>
      <li class="brodcastText "></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="leaveCommentDv">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="leaveComment" data-ajax-coments-res="26" data-parent-message-id="0"><i class="chatGrey"></i>Leave a Comment</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="dig dig26" data-message-id="26" data-parent-message-id="0"><i class="thumbGrey"></i>Dig it</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="ajaxComentsRes26" class="ajaxComentsRes"></div>
</div>
```

Note that I added the blue color, too! :)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `closest` wont work here. Use `find` instead. also use `data` to extract data instead of `attr`

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.remainingTimeDv .font-sm .cursorDefault', function(event) {
    var messageId = $(this).parents().find('.leaveCommentDv').find('a:first').data('ajax-coments-res');
    alert(messageId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messageContentRow">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="userName hover-no-underline">Erick Venere</a>
    <p></p>
    <p>Vel ab eius consequat Consequatur Labore sunt<br></p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="remainingTimeDv">
        <ul>
            <li class="font-sm">22 minutes ago
                <span class="cursorDefault" title="Emma Caldarera">(to Multiple Staff)</span>
            </li>
            <li class="brodcastText "></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="leaveCommentDv">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="leaveComment" data-ajax-coments-res="26" data-parent-message-id="0"><i class="chatGrey"></i>Leave a Comment</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="dig dig26" data-message-id="26" data-parent-message-id="0"><i class="thumbGrey"></i>Dig it</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="ajaxComentsRes26" class="ajaxComentsRes"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```js
$(function() {

  $(document.body).on('click', '.remainingTimeDv .font-sm .cursorDefault', function(event) {
    var messageId = $(this).parents().find('.leaveCommentDv:first a:first').data('ajax-coments-res');
    alert(messageId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messageContentRow">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="userName hover-no-underline">Erick Venere</a>
  <p></p>
  <p>Vel ab eius consequat Consequatur Labore sunt<br></p>
  <p></p>
  <div class="remainingTimeDv">
    <ul>
      <li class="font-sm">22 minutes ago
        <span class="cursorDefault" title="Emma Caldarera">(to Multiple Staff)</span>
      </li>
      <li class="brodcastText "></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="leaveCommentDv">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="leaveComment" data-ajax-coments-res="26" data-parent-message-id="0"><i class="chatGrey"></i>Leave a Comment</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="dig dig26" data-message-id="26" data-parent-message-id="0"><i class="thumbGrey"></i>Dig it</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="ajaxComentsRes26" class="ajaxComentsRes"></div>
</div>
```

The reason your original did not work is because `closest()` doesn't do what you appeared to think it does. It doesn't find the nearest element or child element to the selection, it finds the nearest *ancestor*, and the "cursorDefault" element doesn't have any ancestors matching "leaveCommentDv". Check https://api.jquery.com/closest/ for a description of that method.